# (nodejs, javascript) How would I go about using a variable to find objects in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

So I have this code:

```
var content = fs.readFileSync("timezones.json");

var body = JSON.parse(content)

var user = user.whatever.id;

console.log(user + "'s timezone: " + body.table.user.timezone);
```

I have a JSON that records someones user ID, and then their timezone.

```
{ "table": [
  {
    "221757857836564485": [
      {
        "timezone": "timezone1"
```

The way I want to get someones timezone is to have `user` be the ID of whoever is selected, eg if the users ID is "12345", I want to find

```
{ "table": [
  {
    "12345": [
      {
        "timezone": "timezone"
```

I was just wondering how I would implement the ID into `body.table.user.timezone`, or if I should have my JSON file structured differently?

Comment: What is ```user = user.whatever.id```? ```user``` isn't defined anywhere before this.

Comment: Did u try body.table[userId].timezone?

Comment: Your data structure is confusing me.  What else is in the object holding `table`?  And how about inside the table, and inside the user object?  Something like `const table = {'12345': {timezone: 'some zone', ...}, ...}` would make sense to me.  But I don't get this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try restructuring your JSON this way:

{ "table": [
  { "user": "12345",
    "timezone": "timezone1"
  },

and so on. You can then reference the first user as body.table[0].user and the corresponding timezone as body.table[0].timezone. "user" needs to be a key to be referenced.

Comment: That's still more complex than `const table = {'12345': {timezone: 'tz1', ...}, ...}`.  That would make it trivial to look up.